# jQuery: Center fancybox in viewport

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox-2

I am currently using fancybox version 2 to display my images when a thumbnail is clicked but I can't seem to get the fancybox to sit in the middle of the viewport, vertically speaking, since horizontally it's fine.

I've tried quite a few things and this is the latest:

**CSS**

```
.fancybox-wrap { 
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 50px !important;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox-wrap").css("position", "absolute");

    // fancybox initialisation etc

});


$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('.fancybox-wrap').css('top', $(this).scrollTop() + "50px");
});
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you using Fancybox V2? The demo page here ( http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ ) seems to work fine centering on both axis. Can you gve a link to your page?

Comment: Hi @BillyMoat, I would but it's on a dev server and IP restriced :/
also, I think fancy box is centering it fine based on page dimensions but I need to center based on the actual viewport of the browser as I am using it in a facebook canvas app page which is quite tall and depending on the current scroll position you need to scroll up/down to fit the image in the viewport

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(window).bind('resize', function() {
    var top = ($(window).height() / 2) - ($(".fancybox-wrap").outerHeight() / 2);
    var left = ($(window).width() / 2) - ($(".fancybox-wrap").outerWidth() / 2);
    $(".fancybox-wrap").css({ top: top, left: left});
}).trigger('resize');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aGhxK/23/

Answer (score 4):

The only thing you need to do is add to website css

```
html, body {height: 100%;}
```

And fancybox will position image at the screen center instead of page center.

Answer (score 0):

This sets `left` and `top` using `position: absolute` dinamically:

http://jsfiddle.net/aGhxK/1/

Comment: Hi @Vitor Ussui, thanks for your answer, I think your answer is working fine but it looks as if the fancybox is centered based on the total page height rather ran the viewport height?

Comment: Then you just change `$(window)` for `$(document)`. The problem is you won't see it if you're not in the middle of the page (assuming it's higher than the viewport). In that case, try this [http://jsfiddle.net/aGhxK/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/aGhxK/5/), so the box will always be centered, even if you scroll down.

Comment: the latest fiddle is perfect but for some reason my lightbox is still in the middle of the page but when I scroll up or down it doesn't stay in the viewport, don't know why....

Comment: Have you inspected your lightbox element to see if it's static or absolute? Also, make sure you use $(window) in jQuery.

Comment: I think it may have something to do with the facebook app canvas page as Billy Moat pointed out, on the fancybox 2 demo page the fancyboxes are actually appearing exactly in the centre of the viewport but it's not happening for me for some reason.