# how to place my fancybox always in the center of the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I’m an old french newbie. I have a question about Fancybox.
My skills in javascript and in programming are new.
So thanks for your understanding

I have many thumbs which number come from a folder.
Each Thumb can open a fancy box to display a slideshow with associate pictures
I manage to do what I wanted but another problem appeared,
**there is always a problem The fancybox window centers in the div and not in the window.**
The greater the number of thhumbs, the greater is the div.
And the more the fancy box opening shifts towards the bottom until it disappears from the window.

I use the standard Fancybox 2.1.5 js and css

So thank you for your help
and hope my english is clear enough

**here is the javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".image-show").fancybox({
        padding         : 15,
        fitToView   : true,
    });

    $('.open-album').click(function(e) {
        var el, id = $(this).data('open-id');
        if(id){
            el = $('.image-show[rel=' + id + ']:eq(0)');
            e.preventDefault();
            el.click();
        }
    });         
});
```

**here is the html:**

```
<div class="boite_real">
    <div class="real"> <img src="<?php echo $image ; ?>" alt="vignette realisations" /> </div>
    <div class="monbloc">                                       
        <div class="layout">                                
             <div class="layout-wrapper">                           
                  <div class="layout-content">                      
                    <div class="texte"> 
                        <a href="#" class="open-album" aria-haspopup="true" data-open-id="album-<?php echo $valeurBoucle; ?>">  
                            <h3><?php echo $titre; ?></h3>
                        </a>
                        <p><?php  echo $texte; ?></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- content of slideshow in display none-->
    <div id="gallery_one" style="display: none;">
        <?php
            $monfolder = "./Photos_realisations_$id";
            if(is_dir($monfolder))
            {
                $dossier = opendir($monfolder);         // j'ouvre le dossier
                $bdd_array = array();               // je créé un tableau
                while ($Fichier = readdir($dossier))    // je lis chaque élément contenu dans le dossier avec une boucle while
                {
                    if(!in_array($Fichier,array(".","..",".DS_Store"))) // si l'element lu, n'est pas l'un des éléments suivants
                    {
                        $bdd_array[] = $Fichier;    // je rajoute l'élément au tableau
                    }
                }  
                sort($bdd_array);                   // je trie mon tableau
                foreach($bdd_array as $File)            //pour chaque éléments du tableau
                {
                    $nomFichier = $File;
                    if( strstr($nomFichier, 'site'))    //Code à exécuter si la sous-chaine chaine2 est trouvée dans chaine1 
                    { 
                        $nomFichier = $File;

        ?>
                        <a  rel ="<?php echo $album; ?>" class="image-show" href="<?php echo $monfolder."/".$nomFichier; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $monfolder."/".$nomFichier; ?>" alt=""/></a>          
        <?php
                    }           // fin if  
                }               // fin foreach
                closedir($dossier); // je ferme le dossier
            }       
        ?>
    </div> <!--fin gallery_one-->
</div>
```

**here is the CSS**

```
.boite_real{
    float: left;width: 24%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 1.25%;
    position: relative;
}

.real{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 13px;color: #3C3C3B;
    background-image: url('fond_blanc.png');
    background-repeat: repeat;
}

.boite_real:nth-child(4n+0){ margin-right: 0;}

.real div{ ont-size: 12px;line-height: 13px;margin: 5px;}

.real div div{
    margin: 0 auto;text-align: center;width: 100%;
    font-size: 13px;font-weight: 700;padding-top: 5px;
}

 .monbloc{
    position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 99.9999%;overflow: hidden;
    background: transparent;
 }

    .layout {
        display: table;
        height: 100%;width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-align: center;
        *position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .layout-wrapper {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 100%;
        *left: 0;
        *position: absolute;
        *top: 50%;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
        -webkit-transition: background .5s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: background .5s ease-out;
        -o-transition: background .5s ease-out;
        transition: background .5s ease-out;
    }

    .layout-wrapper:hover {background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);}

    .layout-content {
        display: -moz-inline-stack;
        display: inline-block;
        *display: inline;
        *left: 0;
        *position: relative;
        *zoom: 1;
        *top: -50%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .layout-content {  display: none; }

    .layout-wrapper:hover .layout-content{ display: -moz-inline-stack;display: inline-block;}
```

Comment: Please check [jQuery: Center fancybox in viewport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075734/jquery-center-fancybox-in-viewport), [jquery fancybox content not centering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21199737/jquery-fancybox-content-not-centering-in-chrome)

Answer (score -2):

For horizontal placement you can set the following style on the fancybox container, provided it's in a context that is the full width of the viewport:

```
margin:0 auto;
```

For vertical centering... well, there are various methods that more or less work.

[This should help for centering in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

Comment: no problem with the horizontal centering.
that is only with the vertical centering.
it operates with the height of the div and not with the height on the window.
And in this case, when you have too many item the height of the div is bigger than the window and when you want to open fancybox it's opening at the bottom or outside the window